# Specific error messages using ReactiveUI's ReactiveValidatedObject?

Tags: c#, validation, mvvm, reactiveui, wpf-4.5

Say I have an Email property and i want to show 2 different specific error messages like "required" or "invalid format" accordingly to provide a better user experience... how do I do that?

Comment: Maybe helpful or at least a start @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115509/reactiveui-and-validation/7128527#7128527

Answer (score 0):

If you need more control over validation, I'd suggest giving [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) a try. It integrates nicely with any MVVM framework and by using InlineValidator you can tackle more complex validation scenarios compared to property based validation. I'm using it myself in most of my projects.